# Somehow Facebook login does NOT work because of faveicon with an empty href

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

**Update**

So I finally found what was the problem. A *favicon* with an empty `href` attribute:

```
<link rel="icon" href="">
```

It was changine the state value of the Facebook API, however it wasn't making any extra GET request whatsoever. Also if I had any output before this line, it would work just as expected.

I'm wondering how does this can cause such a problem, even without making any extra HTTP request? There were other output above and below this line which adding or removing any of them make no difference at all. What is special about this tiny line of code? Could it actually send an HTTP request that doesn't show up in the browser console?

**Original Question**

I have abstracted Facebook SDK v4 in a class as you can see below. The problem I'm facing is that in some situations, on the `$cfg['facebook']['login_redirect_url']` page, the `FB::CheckLogin()` doesn't work unless I output something to the page.

I'm wondering if there is something here I'm missing or I have overlooked.

The `$cfg['facebook']['login_redirect_url']` page:

```
if ( FB::CheckLogin() ) {

    $user_facebook_data = FB::UserData();

    /* Setting up user session ... */

} else {
    throw new Exception( 'Facebook Login Failed' );
}

header( 'Location: ' . $cfg['url'] . '/' );
```

This is included in every page:

```
FB::AppID( $cfg['facebook']['app_id'] );
FB::AppSecret( $cfg['facebook']['app_secret'] );
FB::LoginRedirect( $cfg['facebook']['login_redirect_url'] );
FB::Scope( 'email' );

FB::Start();
FB::Connect();
```

My Facebook abstraction:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

abstract class FB {

    private static $app_id = null;
    private static $app_secret = null;
    private static $login_redirect_url = null;
    private static $scope = null;
    private static $helper = null;
    private static $login_url = null;
    private static $session = null;
    private static $user_data = null;
    private static $login = false;
    private static $redirect_uri = null;

    public static function Start () {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/../libraries/facebook-sdk/autoload.php';

        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( self::$app_id, self::$app_secret );

        self::$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( self::$login_redirect_url );
    }

    public static function Connect () {

        if ( !empty( $_SESSION ) && !empty( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {

            self::$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

            try {

                if ( self::$session->validate() ) {
                    self::$login = true;
                } else {
                    self::$session = null;
                    self::$login = false;
                }

            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                self::$session = null;
            }

        } else {

            try {
                self::$session = self::$helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
            } catch( FacebookRequestException $e ) {
                echo $e->message;
            } catch( Exception $e ) {
                echo $e->message;
            }
        }

        if ( !empty(self::$session) ) {
            self::$login = true;
        }

        if ( self::CheckLogin() ) {

            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = self::$session->getToken();
            self::$session = new FacebookSession( self::$session->getToken() );

            $request = new FacebookRequest( self::$session, 'GET', '/me' );
            $response = $request->execute();
            self::$user_data = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
        }
    }

    public static function AppID ( $app_id ) {
        self::$app_id = $app_id;
    }

    public static function AppSecret ( $app_secret ) {
        self::$app_secret = $app_secret;
    }

    public static function LoginRedirect ( $login_redirect_url ) {
        self::$login_redirect_url = $login_redirect_url;
    }

    public static function Scope ( $scope ) {
        self::$scope = $scope;
    }

    public static function UserData () {
        return self::$user_data;
    }

    public static function LoginURL () {

        if ( empty(self::$login_url) ) {

            self::$login_url = self::$helper->getLoginUrl( array(
                    'scope' => self::$scope
                )
            );
        }

        return self::$login_url;
    }

    public static function CheckLogin () {

        if ( !empty(self::$session) && true === self::$login ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static function RedirectURI ( $redirect_uri ) {
        self::$redirect_uri = $redirect_uri;
    }

    public static function FixURLHash () {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
                if (window.history && history.pushState) {
                    window.history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
                } else {
                    var scroll = {
                        top: document.body.scrollTop,
                        left: document.body.scrollLeft
                    };
                    window.location.hash = '';
                    document.body.scrollTop = scroll.top;
                    document.body.scrollLeft = scroll.left;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your domain url given while creating facebook app for your page. It may be the problem of "http://" or "https://". Remove "http://www." or "https://www." from your domain url in facebook app. Keep only "urdomain.com". Hope this works

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The domain url is fine. I guess the problem is something with the `state` changing somewhere, somehow ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a header redirect, why not try using a JavaScript redirect. Change:

```
header( 'Location: ' . $cfg['url'] . '/' );
```

to:

```
echo '<script>window.location = "'. $cfg['url'] .'";</script>';
```

This should help you solve the problem of outputting something to the page and keep the redirect.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't solve the problem also. For some reason the `state` is changed somewhere, unless if output something after connecting to the graph api. It might be `mod_rewrite` issue as well. Thanks again.